# Retrofit2 failed to upload image with Multipart or RequestBody

Tags: android, postman, retrofit, retrofit2, multipartform-data

I've tried couple of approaches to send image for server just like it works in Postman
[image]

but none actually worked out.

**The first way via @Multipart:**

```
interface Api {   
@Multipart
@POST("/upload-file")
fun uploadFile(@Part("file") file: RequestBody,
               @Part("data") id: FileUploadModel): Single<Response<AdvertisementResponse>>
}
```

And method in repository class:

```
 override fun uploadFile(
    id: FileUploadModel,
    filePath: String
): Single<Response<AdvertisementResponse>> {

    val requestFile = RequestBody.create(MediaType.parse("image/*"), file)

    return api.uploadFile(requestFile, id)
}
```

**The second way using RequestBody:**

```
 @POST("/upload-file")
 fun uploadFile(@Body requestBody: RequestBody): Single<Response<AdvertisementResponse>>
```

And method in repository class:

```
override fun uploadFile(
    id: FileUploadModel,
    filePath: String
): Single<Response<AdvertisementResponse>> {

    val file = File(filePath)
    val builder = MultipartBody.Builder()
    builder.setType(MultipartBody.FORM)

    val requestFile = RequestBody.create(MediaType.parse("image/*"), file)

    builder.addFormDataPart("file", file.name, requestFile)
    builder.addFormDataPart("data", id.toJson())

    return api.uploadFile(builder.build())
}
```

**The third way via MultipartBody.Part:**

```
@Multipart
@POST("/upload-file")
fun uploadFile(@Part("file") file: MultipartBody.Part,
               @Part("data") id: FileUploadModel): Single<Response<AdvertisementResponse>>
```

And method in repository class:

```
 override fun uploadFile(
    id: FileUploadModel,
    filePath: String
): Single<Response<AdvertisementResponse>> {

    val file = File(filePath)
    val requestFile = RequestBody.create(MediaType.parse("image/*"), file)
    val multipartFile = MultipartBody.Part.createFormData("file", file.name, requestFile)

    return api.uploadFile(multipartFile, id)
}
```

Logs shows that the POST request for upload-file is not finished:

> 2020-08-15 13:52:35.828  D/OkHttpInterceptor: --> POST http://####/advertisement
> 2020-08-15 13:52:35.829  D/OkHttpInterceptor: Content-Type: application/json
> 2020-08-15 13:52:35.829  D/OkHttpInterceptor: Content-Length: 233
> 2020-08-15 13:52:35.829  D/OkHttpInterceptor: {"businessName":"mgskhsgmhz","email":"test@email.com","emirates":"Abu Dhabi","image":"/storage/emulated/0/Pictures/1768cbfe-e5eb-4ae0-b642-be2733cfedbe969168674235591475.jpg","note":"","ownerName":"mhzm","phone":"1111","website":""}
> 2020-08-15 13:52:35.829  D/OkHttpInterceptor: --> END POST (233-byte body)
> 2020-08-15 13:52:36.233  D/OkHttpInterceptor: <-- 201 Created http://####/advertisement (403ms)
> 2020-08-15 13:52:36.233  D/OkHttpInterceptor: X-Powered-By: Express
> 2020-08-15 13:52:36.234  D/OkHttpInterceptor: Access-Control-Allow-Origin: *
> 2020-08-15 13:52:36.234  D/OkHttpInterceptor: Content-Type: application/json; charset=utf-8
> 2020-08-15 13:52:36.234  D/OkHttpInterceptor: Content-Length: 303
> 2020-08-15 13:52:36.235  D/OkHttpInterceptor: ETag: W/"12f-hAPhr6BG9nzrhDMQ2eMpt2ypCAk"
> 2020-08-15 13:52:36.235  D/OkHttpInterceptor: Date: Sat, 15 Aug 2020 10:52:37 GMT
> 2020-08-15 13:52:36.235  D/OkHttpInterceptor: Connection: keep-alive
> 2020-08-15 13:52:36.237  D/OkHttpInterceptor: {"Error":{},"Data":{"_id":"5f37be7552e7000012180324","businessName":"mgskhsgmhz","email":"test@email.com","emirates":"Abu Dhabi","image":"/storage/emulated/0/Pictures/1768cbfe-e5eb-4ae0-b642-be2733cfedbe969168674235591475.jpg","note":"","ownerName":"mhzm","phone":"1111","website":""},"HasError":false}
> 2020-08-15 13:52:36.237  D/OkHttpInterceptor: <-- END HTTP (303-byte body)
> 2020-08-15 13:52:36.244  D/123: sent: 5f37be7552e7000012180324
> 2020-08-15 13:52:36.278  D/OkHttpInterceptor: --> POST http://####/upload-file
> 2020-08-15 13:52:36.278  D/OkHttpInterceptor: Content-Type: multipart/form-data; boundary=894cbe1b-0fc4-47c6-849d-3764193c214f
> 2020-08-15 13:52:36.279  D/OkHttpInterceptor: Content-Length: 104305

I wonder why Retrofit can't complete such requests.

Thanks for any suggestions

Cheers

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The issue were caused by inability to read the file from disk.

Adding `android:requestLegacyExternalStorage="true"` to the Android Manifest worked for me with Android sdk 29.

```
<application
android:name=".MyApplication"
android:requestLegacyExternalStorage="true" ...
```

Apart from adding `<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.READ_EXTERNAL_STORAGE" />` permission.

Comment: it will only work on android 10 but  not on above it.